# TensorFlow - Change 1 to 0 in a tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to change the value in tensor `t` to `a` where its value is `b`, which can be expressed in numpy as:

```
t[t == b] = a
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This creates a new tensor as specified:

```
t2 = tf.where( tf.equal( b, t ), a * tf.ones_like( t ), t )
```

If you want to *change* the value of `t` you can only do that if `t` is a variable, not a simple tensor, and then you can use `assign`:

```
tf.assign( t, t2 )
```